# How to change a light switch with 3 sets of wiring

Tags: light-fixture

I have 3  sets of wires. The 3 grounds are together with a wire twist, the 3 neutrals (white wires)are tied together with an wire twist. 2 blacks are pig tailed and one is alone. No switch just a plate to cover the wires,  want to add a switch

Comment: Just to clarify: the stated wiring bundles were there under the cover plate, and you want to add a switch in there now? Also, what is the switch going to control, and is that controlled item's power and neutral in this box?

Comment: Do you know why it is done like that?  The lone black should also have a lone white/neutral.  I imagine one the pigtail blacks is power.

Comment: How about some pictures of the wiring set up? Also, is this a switch or light-fixture as you've got it tagged?

Comment: @crip659 Not necessarily. Unless it was a switch loop, it is quite normal to have "all white/neutral together". But we are dealing with some unknowns at the moment.

Comment: Are you adding a *new* switch? Or replacing an *existing* switch? Possibly a big difference, and the title says "change" but the text says "add". **Please clarify.**

Comment: Also, is the new switch a simply on/off mechanical switch? Or is it a dimmer/smart switch/WiFi/timer/motion sensor/etc.?